# How can i see The full Inner Working of an OkHttp Client? Retrofit Socket Closed Time Out

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, okhttp

Hello thank you very much for your time, I am having an unknown issue with retrofit, the only lead I have is a socket closed/timeout message, so I think I may help me to have more info on how the okhttp client and retrofit works, and since I understand sockets have to do more with HTTP clients I would like to know more on the inner workings behind an okhttp client as that may lead to a solution.

So this is my issue.

I am having an issue were by using retrofit to get some data via Post on an android application one of my CallBacks never comes back with a response body even though other calls in the same Web Service are stable and work fine. This error is rather random and it only happens while using retrofit on an android application, while using postman or using the API on a web browser works just fine.

The only way that I have been able to replicate the error consistently is by switching the Network type on the android emulator from Full to HSDPA or any other network type different from full or LTE.

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/8bgCxtr" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/8bgCxtr"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This is some responses I get by the Throwable on Failure Calls

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
detail message: timeout

I have tried increasing the Timeout on the OkHttp Client and instead of a timeout error, I get a Socket Closed.
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
detail message: Socket closed

[image: Socket Closed]

With no more information on the error than those simple lines, so I searched a way to get more information and I found that I could set a logg interceptor on the OkHttp client to get more info on the issue, but what I got was not enough for me to see a possible solution.

This is the logg I get when the call returns correctly :

> D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.68:83/api/Comercios/comercios
>
> D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>
> D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 418
>
> D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfVXNlck5hbWUiOiJVU0VSX0JPTkFOWkExIiwiX0hhc2giOiI1U1FGQUEiLCJqdGkiOiIzNmNmYTZlOS01ODk3LTQ0NjYtYjA0Mi1kZGVkMDBiZGU5ZDAiLCJleHAiOjE1ODE0ODAxMjUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODMiLCJhdWQiOiJNeVRlc3RBcGkifQ.9xAkkMxRpUEFMNdQaZvVTYQIEc-8w22fl_ubIAVaqi4
>
> D/OkHttp:
>   {"anyObjects":{"idGrupo":"00d60025-6fb9-484f-97f0-08d79dfdbf92"},"cultura":"","hash":"5SQFAA","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfVXNlck5hbWUiOiJVU0VSX0JPTkFOWkExIiwiX0hhc2giOiI1U1FGQUEiLCJqdGkiOiIzNmNmYTZlOS01ODk3LTQ0NjYtYjA0Mi1kZGVkMDBiZGU5ZDAiLCJleHAiOjE1ODE0ODAxMjUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODMiLCJhdWQiOiJNeVRlc3RBcGkifQ.9xAkkMxRpUEFMNdQaZvVTYQIEc-8w22fl_ubIAVaqi4","usuario":"USER_BONANZA1"}
>
> D/OkHttp: --> END POST (418-byte body)
>
> D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.1.68:83/api/Comercios/comercios
>   (66ms)
>
> D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> D/OkHttp: Server: Kestrel
>
> D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 01:03:01 GMT
>
> https://pastebin.com/wRwnMrsk 2020-02-11 19:02:59.515
>
> D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (276837-byte body)

The response body is in a paste bin, too long to be on this post.

and this is when the call gets a time out or a socket closed

> D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.68:83/api/Comercios/comercios
>   D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 D/OkHttp:
>   Content-Length: 418 D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfVXNlck5hbWUiOiJVU0VSX0JPTkFOWkExIiwiX0hhc2giOiJCRFo1R0EiLCJqdGkiOiI0NmI0MTA0NC03M2M2LTQ5MDEtOTcyMy0yZjE1NjE1ODgzZDgiLCJleHAiOjE1ODE0ODAzMjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODMiLCJhdWQiOiJNeVRlc3RBcGkifQ.EgVFlAzqOlV-RpjRRxXpQzp3q3kk1FqTcoaGDQBY0XA
>
> D/OkHttp:
>   {"anyObjects":{"idGrupo":"00d60025-6fb9-484f-97f0-08d79dfdbf92"},"cultura":"","hash":"BDZ5GA","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfVXNlck5hbWUiOiJVU0VSX0JPTkFOWkExIiwiX0hhc2giOiJCRFo1R0EiLCJqdGkiOiI0NmI0MTA0NC03M2M2LTQ5MDEtOTcyMy0yZjE1NjE1ODgzZDgiLCJleHAiOjE1ODE0ODAzMjMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODMiLCJhdWQiOiJNeVRlc3RBcGkifQ.EgVFlAzqOlV-RpjRRxXpQzp3q3kk1FqTcoaGDQBY0XA","usuario":"USER_BONANZA1"}
>
> D/OkHttp: --> END POST (418-byte body)
>
> D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.1.68:83/api/Comercios/comercios
>   (34ms)
>
> D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> D/OkHttp: Server: Kestrel
>
> D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 01:05:45 GMT

It simply returns an empty body with no other explanation on why.

When searching the socket closed error or the time out, it has been mostly dead ends, saying that it has to do with the server and not the application, I spoke with the person that manages the API and the server and time and time again I have been told that from their side there is nothing wrong, at least that they know, One thing that they mention is that maybe the byte size of the body is too big and that's why is not allowing is closing the socket randomly, but I do not know how to keep it open or if that is the issue in the first place.

So I would like to know if there is a way to see a more detailed log of what's going on with the Okhttp server so I can better search for a possible solution.

I am going to post my code here, the model I send to the Webservice is fine that's not the issue because if the structure is not as the servers expect it to be I receive an onSuccess Response with a detailed error of what I did wrong from the server, is just when everything is okay, that I receive a timeout or a socket closed plus, some times it works some times it doesn't ( Not a server issue according to postman and my peers) But it never works when I switch the network type on the android emulator and i have shown before in the post.

This are my Gradle implementations

---

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'
```

This is how I build my Client and retrofit

---

```
private fun buildRetrofit(): Retrofit {

    val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logger.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    val client = OkHttpClient()
        .newBuilder()
        .addInterceptor(logger)
        .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(FN.returnWebAPI(this))
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

}
```

This is how I make the call, now is just receiving a response body to be sure it doesn't have to do with the parsing of the data.

---

```
val idGrupoComercios = hashMapOf("idGrupo" to id)
                val hashComercio = HashComercio(hash, upperU.usuario.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()), "", jwt.toString(), idGrupoComercios
                )
            val callComercios: Call<ResponseBody> =
                service.getComercios(tokenBearer, hashComercio)

            callComercios.enqueue(object :
                Callback<ResponseBody> {
                override fun onFailure(
                    call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                    t: Throwable
                ) {
                    Crashlytics.logException(t)

                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                    response: Response<ResponseBody>
                ) {
                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                       val data = response.body()!!

                }

            })
```

So any help or ideas on what I can do would be of great help, I am in a position where it seems i can do something from the app side of the project, so any help would be great.

Comment: probably paste the full log (with some stuff removed) by using https://pastebin.com/ and share the link. The full logs ideally would help someone to see what is going on.

Comment: The full HtttpLoginterceptor log is on the pastebin i posted above, https://pastebin.com/wRwnMrsk 
But if you ment the Logcat or Java console Log, That's the issue the console does not give me more information at least the way use it.
The log is only two lines
 Socket Closed. java.net.SocketException: Socket closed detail message: Socket closed that't it no more info , that's why i am looking for a way to get more info.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to find a sort of exit to the issue.
In the past, the highest time out I tried was for 5 minutes when building the client, but it seems like the socket it builds closes if you don't max it out so I changed the timeout to one day that way it maxed out the timeout it can take.

And the android system or the server is not really going to wait a day for a response, so, for the most part, it delivers a response if the server does not reset the connection.

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

In those cases, you simply put true on the retryOnConnectionFailure, and even though it takes more time to return an answer it will deliver one.

I talked to the person that manages the servers and told me that the issue is that the HTTP client or retrofit fail to reconstruct the message in the first try, and subsequent tries are more likely to fail if the response body is too long using a 3g Connection, also if it contains images or hash values inside the json , as I was doing 
putting a hash for a complete image on the json.

This is the code for the client

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .callTimeout(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .hostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier { hostname, session -> true })
            .build()
```

Also he told me that for best results json when using HSDPA should be smaller than 1024 bytes with header and all. up to 2024 bytes Response bodies.